# Cakephp3 Tiny Auth Allow Auth fail

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am using the TinyAuth plugin with my Cakephp3. I have a controller with the following namespace:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api\Datatables;
```

The controller is Listings and my function is Filter

I have the following route setup:

```
Router::scope('/datatables', ['prefix' => 'api/datatables'], function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml', 'ajax']);   
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

This allows me to call the following url:

```
/datatables/listings/filter.json
```

I want to allow the filter function:

```
datatables/Listings = filter
```

When I call my URL I am re-directed to login. If I login the url works, so the allow_auth works.

I have also tried the following:

```
api/datatables/Listings = filter
api/Datatables/Listings = filter
Api/Datatables/Listings = filter
api/datatables/Listings = filter
datatables/Listings = filter
Datatables/Listings = filter
api/Listings = filter
```

No matter what the path is not allowed. If I move the controller to the default location then in allow_auth:

```
Listings = filter
```

the filter function is accessible without authorisation. This suggests that there is a problem with the plugin when using a router scope.

Here is the plugin's composer.json

```
{
    "name": "ypnos-web/cakephp-datatables",
    "description": "jQuery DataTables for CakePHP 3",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/ypnos-web/cakephp-datatables",
    "type": "cakephp-plugin",
    "keywords": ["cakephp", "datatables"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Frank Heider",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/fheider",
            "role": "Author"
        },
        {
            "name": "Johannes Jordan",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/ypnos-web",
            "role": "Author"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "^3.6"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "DataTables\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "DataTables\\Test\\": "tests",
            "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I correct in stating that the slashed routes do work for the acl.ini - they seem to as far as I can see.

I am using the slashed routes to better organise my functions.

My request params are as follows when I call /datatables/listings/filter.json?

```
'controller' => 'Listings',
    'action' => 'filter',
    'pass' => [],
    'prefix' => 'api/datatables',
    'plugin' => null,
    '_ext' => 'json',
    '_matchedRoute' => '/datatables/:controller/:action/*',
    '?' => [
        'string' => 'seat'
    ]
```

If I call /api/datatables/listings/filter.json:

Controller class Datatables could not be found.

Comment: I am curious what $this->request->params contains, what kind of data is in the routing array here? That is what counts, not your namespace (PHP internals) or slash prefix (public URL internals)

Comment: @mark where should I debug my request params?

Comment: inside the controller you are trying to debug and where access doesnt work
right inside the initialize() etc for example

Comment: pls see my updated question for the params

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with the plugin, but `api/datatables/Listings` seems to be the correct format, however looking at the plugin's source, it seems that nested prefixes aren't supported:

```
if (strpos($key, '/') !== false) {
    list($res['prefix'], $key) = explode('/', $key);
}
```

**https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth/blob/1.11.0/src/Utility/Utility.php#L23-L25**

That code would parse `api` as the prefix, and `datatables` as the controller.

You may want to open an issue, or add support for it yourself if you can.

Comment: Yeah I dont think multi slashes are even a valid/expected thing in CakePHP in general. Those should be avoided. But yours seems to be a different problem. You are using the generated routes rather then the documented default URL parts. Please post also your actual plugin name and the composer.json for it.

Comment: @mark You probably wanted to comment on the question instead :) Anyways, that's how nested prefixes are supposed to be expressed in CakePHP? Or are you referring to the auth plugin using a slash for separating prefix and controller?

Comment: True, I added a comment to the question. As for your answer: If that fixes the issue I am happy to accept a PR that includes this change of using the last / instead of the first.

Comment: @mark let me check on the request data, also regarding the question of nexsted prefixes, I simply followed the principle of the 'admin' or 'manager' routes as documented in the book.

Comment: Thank you for the support - https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth/pull/104 should solve this. Please confirm.

Comment: Ok I think it works. In my auth_allow I have api/datatables/Listings = filter. I am calling datatables/filter.json and I receive a reply. One last question, I had to paste your PR into the plugin, I did try composer update first

Comment: Released now in https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth/releases/tag/1.12.1